# How to Roll a Layout with scroll view like wheel

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-animation

Hi friends i am facing problem that is i want a wheel type or network structure layout.i am creating that layout and using some rotate animation and achieved it.my problem is i want user to touch and scroll the wheel type layout from "left to right" or "right to left" and my layout like  [image]

Comment: Check this site http://developer.digitalaria.com/devguide/gama/en/gama/wheel_android.php might be helpful for wheel animation in android.

Comment: that third party library is not working yar. any other solutions

Comment: It works. Did you add the jar file in your project? Try downloading the sample source from zip file and run it.

Comment: ya i did it and it contains jar files but the problem is when i runing my application force close happens.And also debug that code the problem happening from using third party library in xml file

Comment: Shall you post your log cat please.

Comment: Tried these http://regupathybalan.blogspot.in/2013/04/carousel-tutorial.html ?